# Views under ListView are not displayed in Relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some Text1"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some Text2"
        android:layout_below="@id/list"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_below="@id/text"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Above is my layout , listview is scrollable but when i scroll to the bottom of the listview I expect the TextView and ImageView to be rendered after the listview.However they are not shown at all.List view covers the whole page (besides the header at the top) What could I do to render the textview and the imageview below the listview ?

Comment: change your relative layout to linear layout and set the weight for each item.

Comment: Thank you but could you elaborate a bit ? I tried with linear layout with weights but now the text and the image are shown before I scrolled since listview does not cover the whole page, I do not want the user to view the text and the image before scrolling to the bottom of the listview

Comment: if you want to show the text and image in last of the listview in footer then you add footer to listview, footer will be a view xml including text and image..

Comment: Yes that worked,thank you! Would you kindly add it to the answer so I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do it: 
First LinearLayout using weight 1 to Listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some Text1"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some Text2"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

other RelativeLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Some Text1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/text"
        android:layout_below="@id/header" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/image"
        android:text="Some Text2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps.